# How to configure portlet in liferay from web service?

Tags: web-services, liferay, portlet

I can to connect to the liferay throw /api/secure/axis/  and i can to create page and adding portlets on it using web services. But i cant to configure portlets using web services, e.g. i want to set specific web content to the portlet "Web Content Display", or i want to set specific folder to the portlet . How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is unclear and am not sure what you are searching for. 
All settings regarding web content display portlet is liferay is present [here](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Web+Content+Display)

If you are trying to add web content display, then try `iframePortletId = layoutTypePortlet.addPortletId(
                    p_userId, p_portletId, p_columnId,
                    p_position);`

where p_position="56"